# Place a button over an image without using a wrapper div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a chrome extension that blocks certain images on web pages and adds a button to reveal the blocked images. I need this button to appear somewhere within the bounds of the blocked image, as it appears on the screen.

Were I in control of the whole webpage, the natural way to do this would be to wrap the image in a div and position the button relative to that. However in practice this has not worked well, for two reasons:

1. Very frequently, `img` tags are placed in containers that resize the image or hide overflow. Getting the wrapper to match the size the of the actual "image" on the screen is hard to do.
2. Injecting a div into the page tends to cause chaos. It picks up unwanted CSS styling and messes with React or Angular websites.

Currently, I'm just inserting the button as a sibling of the image, position it relative to the image's container, and hoping for the best.

JS:

```js
function blockImage(image){
    image.classList.add('blockedImage');
    let button = makeRevealButtonForImage(image);
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(button, image.nextSibling);
}

function makeRevealButtonForImage(img){
    let template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML =
    '<button type="button" class="reveal-button" ' +
    '">Reveal</button>';
    var button = template.content.firstChild;
    ...
    return button;
}
```

HTML winds up looking like this:

```html
<div>
  <img src="badimage.jpg" class="blockedImage"/>
  <button type="button" class="reveal-button">Reveal</button>
 </div>
```

Essential CSS:

```css
.blockedImage {
    background-image: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/blocked.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    object-position: -99999px 99999px;
}

.reveal-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: you could inject a CSS and use classes with pseudo elements

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like ::before and ::after pseudo-elements work with everything except img tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before